# Does a finitely generated faithful module over an Artinian ring contain a regular element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, artinian

In the text

  Nicholson -- Introduction to Abstract Algebra, 4th Ed (2012)

the claim of exercise $8(b)$ of exercise set $11.1$ is:

  If
  $R$
  is a left artinian ring with
  $1\ne 0$
  , and
  $M$
  is a finitely generated left
  $R$
  -module such that
  $\text{ann}(M)=0$
  , then
  $M$
  has a submodule isomorphic to
  $R$
  .

But in my answer to

$\;\;\;\;\;$
[How to show $\operatorname{ann}(M) = \operatorname{ann}(X)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872735)

I gave a counterexample to the above claim.

I wonder if the claim could be repaired by assuming as an additional hypothesis that $R$ is commutative.

**Question:**

  If
  $R$
  is a commutative artinian ring with
  $1\ne 0$
  , and
  $M$
  is a finitely generated
  $R$
  -module such that
  $\text{ann}(M)=0$
  , must
  $M$
  have a submodule isomorphic to
  $R$
  ?

**Two special cases:** The answer is "yes" if

- $R$ is a field.$\\[4pt]$

  $R$ is finite.

That's as far as I've got.

Comment: Does this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3187153/164860.  Here $R$ is a commutative Artinian ring, $M$ is a faithful $2$-generated $R$-module, and every element of $M$ has nonzero annihilator.   Thus $M$ can't have a submodule isomorphic to $R$.  Note that another special case where the answer is "yes" is if $R$ is any reduced Noetherian ring, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269660/annihilators-of-elements-of-a-finitely-generated-faithful-module-over-a-noetheri

Comment: @Badam Baplan: Thanks for the reference, and yes, the example given in the accepted answer in that link appears to give an answer of "no" to my question. Thanks again. Should I now delete my question?

Comment: Hmm.. I think it's a worthwhile question to keep searchable because it addresses an error in a textbook and points to a useful counterexample (I think it is valuable to reinforce good mse posts by linking to them).  Perhaps you could write up a short answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title to make it more specific / searchable.

Comment: @Badam Baplan: I'll leave it for you or someone else to answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is an unfortunate mistake you found.

For semiperfect rings, there is a notion of the *basic module* of the ring, which is a faithful module that captures a lot about the ring. This is a theorem:

> If $R$ is a semiperfect ring, then right basic module is a summand of any generator of Mod-$R$.

For a commutative Artinian ring, the basic module is just $R$ itself. But the missing ingredient, as you see, is that a faithful module need not be a generator of Mod-$R$.  A ring for which every faithful f.g. module is a generator of Mod-$R$ is called *finitely pseudo-Frobenius*. So the best you can say, I think is

> If $R$ is a commutative, semiperfect, finitely pseudo-Frobenius ring, then $R$ is a summand of every f.g. faithful module.

The nicest class for which this is all true is commutative quasi-Frobenius rings.